# .find vba running slowly

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I need to loop through 1,566 rows and do a .find for each row and compare with 10,691 lines. The thing is, I am concatenating three values together in order to get my search value. It is working very slowly, so I tried to filter by the first value on the 10,691 so it would work more quickly - but no joy! I am using a few functions, letter retrieves the letter of the column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub validate()
Dim gbe As Worksheet, mp As Worksheet, PnS As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, Frng As Range
Dim ITC, TT, BC, y, GCell, sz, t, vList

t = Timer
OptimizeVBA True
ShDel ("Garbage"): Sheets.Add.name = "Garbage": Set gbe = Sheets("Garbage"): Set mp = Sheets("Master"): Set PnS = Sheets("PS")


    ITC = Letter(PnS, "Code"): TT = Letter(PnS, "Type"): BC = Letter(PnS, "BCode")
    mp.Range("M2:O" & mp.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).ClearContents
    PnS.Range((ITC & ":" & ITC & "," & TT & ":" & TT & "," & BC & ":" & BC)).Copy Destination:=gbe.Range("A1")
    gbe.Range("$A$1:$C$" & PnS.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
        Header:=xlYes

        gbe.Range("A1:C" & gbe.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).AutoFilter
        gbe.Range("A1:C" & gbe.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="='", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="='FC"
        gbe.rows("2:" & gbe.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).EntireRow.Delete
        gbe.Range("A1:C" & gbe.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).AutoFilter

        Set rng = gbe.Range("A2:A" & gbe.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
        For Each y In rng
        mp.Range("A1:K" & gbe.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=" & y
        With mp.Range("A2:A" & mp.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Set GCell = .Find(What:=sz, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
            If GCell Is Nothing Then
                mp.Range("O100000").End(xlUp) = PnS.Range(ITC & y.Row)
                mp.Range("O100000").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = PnS.Range(TT & y.Row)
                mp.Range("O100000").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = PnS.Range(BC & y.Row)
            End If
            Set GCell = Nothing
            mp.ShowAllData
        End With

        Next y

    ShDel ("Garbage")

OptimizeVBA False
MsgBox Timer - t

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Find` is painfully slow. Pull your range into a variant array and loop through that searching for your values and doing the concatenation you are looking for.

Comment: I would also recommend looking into `With....End With` to help make your code easier on the eyes.

Comment: I second the propositions offered by @Kyle. Performing all these tasks in memory (instead of the sheet directly) will massively improve the performance. Yet, I am sure that you will get even more helpful insights if you are willing to post this question on the correct site: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is essentially the site where they help you improve working / existing code in terms of speed, security, maintainability, and longevity.

Answer (score 2):

A common suggestion for performing operations on excel sheets is to deactivate certain settings programmatically while executing your code.

Here's a little snippet that I use in many of my projects:

```
Public Sub ExcelDefaultSettings(ByVal isActive As Boolean)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = isActive
        .DisplayAlerts = isActive
        If isActive Then
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Else
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

And then you would just make these two calls before and after your execution:

```
ExcelDefaultSettings isActive:=False  'Before

ExcelDefaultSettings isActive:=True  'After
```

It's not a perfect solution, but it can help tremendously on larger projects.

As @Kyle and @Ralph have said, refactoring your code may also help with improving your execution speed.

Another common piece of advice is to 1) transpose the contents of your range into an array, 2) perform your operations only on the array, and then 3) transpose the array back into your range.

This is a bit more involved than adding a bit of code, but a pretty good explanation about it can be found [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

This is the example they give for a basic loop:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range("A1:B10")
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long
For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
    For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
        Debug.Print Arr(R, C)
    Next C
Next R
```

Comment: Thanks @Den Temple, the function OptimizeVBA True turns off all the settings which would slow down Excel. In terms of the array, there would still be ~1600 values in the array, what I did instead is I created a dummy sheet and copied the two columns with the identifying features and did a delete duplicates between the cells, crude but fast. Thanks for the code!